# Creating memory efficient thumbnails using an NSImageView (cocoa/OSX)

Tags: macos, cocoa, memory-management, image-scaling, nsimageview

I am creating small NSImageViews (32x32 pixels) from large images often 512x512 or even 4096 x 2048 for an extreme test case.  My problem is that with my extreme test case, my applicaiton memory footprint seems to go up by over 15MB when I display my thumbnail, this makes me think the NSImage is being stored in memory as a 4096x2048 instead of 32x32 and I was wondering if there is a way to avoid this.  Here is the process I go through to create the NsImageView:

• First I create an NSImage using initByReferencingFile: (pointing to the 4096x2048 .png file)

• Next I initialize the NSImageView with a call to initWithFrame:

• Then I call setImage: to assign my NSImage to the NSImageView

• Finally I set the NSImageView to NSScaleProportionally

I clearly do nothing to force the NSImage to size down to 32x32 but I have had trouble finding a good way to handle this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply create a new 32x32 `NSImage` from the original and then `release` the original image.

First, create the 32x32 image:

```
NSImage *smallImage = [[NSImage alloc]initWithSize:NSMakeSize(32, 32)];
```

Then, lock focus on the image and draw the original on to it:

```
NSSize originalSize = [originalImage size];
NSRect fromRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, originalSize.width, originalSize.height);
[smallImage lockFocus];
[originalImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 32, 32) fromRect:fromRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0f];
[smallImage unlockFocus];
```

Then you may do as you please with the smaller image:

```
[imageView setImage:smallImage];
```

Remember to `release`!

```
[originalImage release];
[smallImage release];
```