# Get image thumbnail from the path

Tags: c#, cocoa, thumbnails, nsimage, xamarin.mac

inside my xamarin.mac application , I use **SQLite** to save database, profile picture is saved in database too, but I have problems with working big images (for ex. size 4 MB), I just need to save thumbnail of photo , while uploading :

```
imgProfilePicture.Image = new NSImage (path);
Byte [] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (path);
_profilePic = Convert.ToBase64String (bytes);
```

I save base64 string in db.. also , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808887/create-thumbnail-image) is simple solution in c #:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName);
    Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(120, 120, ()=>false, IntPtr.Zero);
    thumb.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "thumb"));
```

I need something like this, need to resize image without cropping it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        NSImage baseImage = new NSImage ("original.jpg", false);
        NSImage tinyImage = new NSImage (new CoreGraphics.CGSize (32, 32));
        tinyImage.LockFocus ();
        baseImage.DrawInRect (new CoreGraphics.CGRect (0, 0, 32, 32), new CoreGraphics.CGRect (0, 0, baseImage.Size.Width, baseImage.Size.Height), NSCompositingOperation.Copy, 1.0f);
        tinyImage.UnlockFocus ();

        NSBitmapImageRep rep = new NSBitmapImageRep (tinyImage.AsTiff ());
        NSData data = rep.RepresentationUsingTypeProperties (NSBitmapImageFileType.Jpeg);
        data.Save ("tiny.jpg", true);
```

Which is https://stackoverflow.com/a/7576710/36782 converted to C#